# How to call a function with dependencies within a 3rd party library

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular. My problem is that I can't figure out how to call a function on a provider (that I've created) from within a block of code that is executed under the context of a 3rd party component. Essentially, I don't know how to inject a reference to my provider inside their code.

Details: I'm using a 3rd party library (datajs) to make HTTP calls using oData syntax. The library allows me to customize the HTTP request before it is executed. I'm want to modify the request to add an authorization header with a function I've written (setAuthHeaderOnHTTPRequest) hanging off my own 'security' provider.

Note: I don't want to modify the 3rd party library.

**Here is my 'security' provider with the function I want to run (setAuthHeaderOnHTTPRequest)**

```
(function() {
angular.module('app.core')
    .factory('security', security);

function security() {
    var service = {
        //...
        setAuthHeaderOnHTTPRequest: setAuthHeaderOnHTTPRequest
    };
    return service;

    function setAuthHeaderOnHTTPRequest(request) {
        // code to add auth header
        return (modifiedRequest);
    }
}
})
```

**Here is the block of code that runs within the context of the 3rd Party component.
How do I inject a reference to my security provider within this block of code?**

```
function configureODataHTTP() {
        //Create a custom HTTP client for Odata calls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365519/consuming-web-api-2-odata-endpoint-requiring-windows-authentication-with-breezej
        var defaultHttpClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;
        var myClient = {
            request: function (request, success, error) {
        // this is where I want to call my function on my 'security' provider
                newRequest = security.setAuthHeaderOnHTTPRequest(oldRequest);
                return defaultHttpClient.request(newRequest, success, error);
            }
        };
        OData.defaultHttpClient = myClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. Use http interceptors already provided by angularjs framework. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors. Don't use that library as you'd need to wrap it in angularjs, in which you're reproducing efforts.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I just need an answer for how to call a function from within a library - ignore the fact that this problem includes an HTTP Request. Note: I can't use interceptors because there is another library using one that overrides the request. Changing the OData.defaultHttpClient is the way that the datajs library expects request modification

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just added a reference to the service I needed to access to $rootScope (after the service started). Then I could access it inside my nested function like this:

```
    // this is where I want to call my function on my 'security' provider
            newRequest = $rootScope.security.setAuthHeaderOnHTTPRequest(oldRequest);
```

I'd really prefer a solution that is less of a hack, but this works.